# How to use str_pad on certain values in a variables using mutate/mutate_if?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I want to pad strings with zeros (on the left) if the number of characters is 2.

Let the dataframe be as follows:

`df<-data.frame(a=c("352","35","54","1"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

I would like to get

```
df
    a
1 352
2 035
3 054
4 1
```

I tried using `mutate_if` as follows:

`df %>% mutate_if(nchar(a)==2,str_pad(a,width=3,side="left",pad="0"))`

`df %>% mutate_if(nchar(vars(a))==2,str_pad(a,width=3,side="left",pad="0"))`

But, both can't work.

I also tried using `mutate` with `replace`:

`df %>% mutate(a=replace(a,which(nchar(a)==2),str_pad(a,width=3,side="left",pad="0")))`

Again, I can't achieve what I want.

Comment: The `==3` is not correct as the 2nd and 3rd have only 2 characters

Comment: @akrun Thanks for pointing that out, I have made the changes. It says `Error: wrong result size (5), expected 3 or 1` now.

Comment: This works `df %>% mutate(a = if_else(nchar(a)==2, str_pad(a,width=3,side="left",pad="0"), a))` for me

Comment: @akrun Why can't `replace` work? Is it because it can only replace all the values with only one value?

Comment: It will create the problem with length.  If you are replacing the condition with a single value, it works, otherwise, you have to subset the 'a' again

Comment: Or another option is `df %>% mutate(a = case_when(nchar(.$a)==2 ~ str_pad(.$a, width = 3, side = "left", pad = "0"), TRUE ~ .$a) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can either use `if_else`

```
df %>% 
   mutate(a = if_else(nchar(a)==2, str_pad(a,width=3,side="left",pad="0"), a))
```

or `case_when`

```
df %>%
     mutate(a = case_when(nchar(.$a)==2 ~ str_pad(.$a, width = 3, side = "left", pad = "0"), 
                TRUE ~ .$a) )
#   a
#1 352
#2 035
#3 054
#4   1
```

Comment: In the case where I want the `FALSE` argument to be a missing value, `NA`, how can this be done? I know there's `factor(NA)`, but there's no `char(NA)` or `character(NA)`.

Comment: @HSNKD You can have `NA_character_`